# .htaccess ModReWrite help

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I am having some trouble with my ReWrite code. Please note that the .htaccess file is in the subdomain folder (...public_html/subdomain/ )

I am simply trying to rewrite a page request:

```
http://subdomain.mysite.com/home
http://subdomain.mysite.com/index.php?page=home
```

My .htaccess file looks like this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_])$ /index.php?page=$1
```

Does anything jump out at you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current rule probably works for urls one character long (after the slash)!

Add a `+` to signify one or more characters, or a `*` for zero or more

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]*)$ /index.php?page=$1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the rules in a .htaccess file, you need to strip the contextual per-directory path prefix from the `RewriteRule` pattern. If the .htaccess file is located in the document root `/`, you need to strip the leading `/`.

Additionally you need to quantify the character set. Otherwise it would only describe *one* character.

So try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

is ok ;)

Comment: Please don't give answer based on thoughts. The code in you answer should be tested.