# Using URL path as a query string for index page without display script filename

Tags: php, apache, url

I have an index page that can be accessed from the URL `http://mysite.com`. I can input query strings `?type=small`, `?type=medium` or `?type=large` so that different results will be displayed. However, I want users to be able to access the site with the URLs `http://mysite.com/small`, `http://mysite.com/medium` and `http://mysite.com/large` respectively instead without creating separate pages.

Can this be done and how?

Comment: Google or Search SO for Apache Mod-Rewrite, which is done via .htacces try keywords like ".htaccess rewrites" .... this post will probably get you the answer to what you need to do... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912037/htaccess-modrewrite-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(small|medium|large) /?type=$1
```

Comment: Yup. I didn't know it is that simple. Thanks :)